# Missing replacemente by a loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

i have the following dataframe

```
id  value  year    audit     
 1     21  2007      NaN         
 1     36  2008     2011   
 1      7  2009      Nan  
 2     44  2007      NaN         
 2     41  2008      Nan   
 2     15  2009      Nan  
 3     51  2007      NaN         
 3     15  2008     2011  
 3     51  2009      Nan  
 4     10  2007      NaN        
 4     12  2008      Nan  
 4     24  2009     2011  
 5     30  2007     2011        
 5     35  2008      Nan   
 5    122  2009      Nan
```

Basically,  I want to create another variable audit2 where all the cells are 2011, if at least one audit is 2011, for each id.

I tried to put an if-statement inside a loop, but I cannot get any results

I would like to get this new dataframe

```
id  value  year    audit    audit2
 1     21  2007      NaN      2011   
 1     36  2008     2011      2011   
 1      7  2009      Nan      2011   
 2     44  2007      NaN      NaN            
 2     41  2008      Nan      NaN         
 2     15  2009      Nan      NaN         
 3     51  2007      NaN      2011      
 3     15  2008     2011      2011   
 3     51  2009      Nan      2011   
 4     10  2007      NaN      2011     
 4     12  2008      Nan      2011   
 4     24  2009     2011      2011   
 5     30  2007     2011      2011     
 5     35  2008      Nan      2011   
 5    122  2009      Nan      2011
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: If you show us the code you tried, we can point out what you did wrong.  If you don't show us any code at all, we can't help.

Comment: Also please provide the data frame, for us to try and help you in a convenient way

Comment: Most likely you are modifying the data structure you are iterating over.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby('id')['audit'].transform(lambda s: s[s.first_valid_index()] if s.first_valid_index() else np.nan)
```

output:

```
>>> df
0     2011.0
1     2011.0
2     2011.0
3        NaN
4        NaN
5        NaN
6     2011.0
7     2011.0
8     2011.0
9     2011.0
10    2011.0
11    2011.0
12    2011.0
13    2011.0
14    2011.0
Name: audit, dtype: float64
```